# coldfusion mysql date issue comparing different years

Tags: mysql, date, coldfusion

I am using the following code to display a link with further details only for upcoming soccer games :

```
<cfset todaydate = dateformat(now(), 'dd/mm/yy') />

<cfif #dateformat(predict.date, "dd/mm/yy")# gte todaydate> LINK </cfif>
```

This works fine to display todays and upcoming games in 2013 but it does not work for games
being played 2014.

Does anyone know what the issue might be ? Thanks.

Comment: `dateFormat()` is for **outputting** dates. If you want to do any processing on dates (comparisons, etc), then use actual date objects (as created by `createDate()` / `parseDateTime()` etc). Also... if you *do* want to compare dates, use `dateCompare()`, not the comparison operators like `gte`, `eq` etc.

Comment: Just some helpful advice that's not really have anything to do with your question. There is no need for pound signs in your cfif statement. When I started out with ColdFusion the best way for me to remember when I have to use the pound signs is when I am outputting the expression/variable or if it has to be in quotes. For example, <cfset foo = "this is an example #bar#"> Otherwise you can just do <cfif dateformat() GTE todaydate></cfif>

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 4):

You need to compare date **objects** not date **strings**. So use [dateCompare()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6dd7.html)

```
<cfif dateCompare(predict.date, now()) GTE 0> LINK </cfif>
```

Comment: .. and to compare the dates only, just add the `d` parameter: `<cfif dateCompare(date1, date2, "d") gte 0>`

Answer (score 1):

baynezy's answer is one way to do it, my preferred way would be

```
<cfif predict.date GTE now()> LINK </cfif>
```

You can compare 2 date objects together just like you'd compare 2 numbers. The syntax is easier (for me) to remember than using `dateCompare`

Also note that the `##` are not needed when you're using a `cfif`

Comment: One difference between the two approaches is that `dateCompare` will implicitly convert the input values to date objects (if they are not date objects already). So unlike `gte` you are assured of getting a date comparison, even if you pass in date *strings* (as in the OP). The input values should really be date objects anyway, but .. a slight difference to keep in mind.

Comment: @Leigh that's a valid point, but if you know both variables are date objects then this way will work as well.

Comment: Leigh's comment might be true, but Matt's method gets top marks for code readability.  DateCompare is one of the least intuitive functions I have every seen.

Comment: @MattBusche - Yeah, I am not knocking that approach, just mentioning it is not a straight equivalent (mostly for the OP). However, I do not think it will work "as is" in this case anyway. A `GTE` comparison includes time. From their code it looks like they want a date only comparison.

Comment: @DanBracuk - I do not find it confusing, but I am used to it from sql server. However, it is comparing apples and oranges. `DateCompare` has greater capabilities than simple `>=, <=,...` comparisons, such as variable precision, so it is not simply a stylistic choice.